# The 'hooks/post-receive' hook was ignored because it's not set as executable

Tags: git, web-hosting

I'm trying to use git to push changes on my live website hosted at one.com.
I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalcomet.be/blog/ssh-and-git-on-one-dot-com/) to set up git on one.com, but when I do `git push web`, I get a hint saying that `The 'hooks/post-receive' hook was ignored because it's not set as executable.`

Yes, I have verified that the post-receive file is executable:

```
user@host:~/website.git/hooks$ ls -al
total 68
drwxrwsr-x 2 website.net website.net 4096 Apr 18 11:01 .
drwxrwsr-x 7 website.net website.net 4096 Apr 18 11:14 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net  478 Apr 18 10:57 applypatch-msg.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net  896 Apr 18 10:57 commit-msg.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net 4655 Apr 18 10:57 fsmonitor-watchman.sample
-rwxr-xr-x 1 website.net website.net   47 Apr 18 11:01 post-receive
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net  189 Apr 18 10:57 post-update.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net  424 Apr 18 10:57 pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net 1643 Apr 18 10:57 pre-commit.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net  416 Apr 18 10:57 pre-merge-commit.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net 1492 Apr 18 10:57 prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net 1374 Apr 18 10:57 pre-push.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net 4898 Apr 18 10:57 pre-rebase.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net  544 Apr 18 10:57 pre-receive.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net 2783 Apr 18 10:57 push-to-checkout.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 website.net website.net 3650 Apr 18 10:57 update.sample
user@host:~/website.git/hooks$
```

Also at the end of the linked guide it says this:

```
# this pushes your site using your first key
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-one-com-key' git push web --force

# this runs the post-receive hook upon connection with the other key, then disconnects
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-one-com-post-receive-key <your-login>@ssh.<your-domain>
```

I added `sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-one-com-key` to my .git/config file instead of `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` as I read this was replaced in GIT v2 or something.
From the guide I can not figure out where I should run the final `ssh -i...` command.

Also for reference, the authorized_keys file on the server contains the following:

```
user@host:~/.ssh$ cat authorized_keys
ssh-rsa one-com-key== user@computer.local
command="cd ~/website.git && sh hooks/post-receive" ssh-rsa post-receive-key== user@computer.local
```

Comment: `Yes, I have verified that the post-receive file is executable.` Sure.... can you show us in the question?

Comment: Did you add `command` in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` like it's [described](https://www.digitalcomet.be/blog/ssh-and-git-on-one-dot-com/#create-your-own-post-receive) in the guide?

Comment: Yes, I added the `command` string to the authorized_keys file on the server.

```user@host:~/.ssh$ cat authorized_keys
ssh-rsa one-com-key== user@computer.local

command="cd ~/website.git && sh hooks/post-receive" ssh-rsa post-receive-key== user@computer.local```

Edit: added to the question.

Comment: There is no way to run `post-receive` hook on `git push` at one.com. To run `post-receive` hook you run the second command `ssh -i ~/.ssh/post-receive-key user@host` after `git push`. You can combine `git push` + second `ssh` in a git alias, shell alias, function or script; I prefer scripts for such things.

Comment: <s>So I should just run `git push`, and ignore the hint. And then run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/post-receive-key <your-login>@ssh.<your-domain>`? This connects me to the ssh session, should I do anything afterwards or just disconnect again?</s>

Comment: "*So I should just run git push, and ignore the hint?*" Yes. "*And then run ssh -i ~/.ssh/post-receive-key <your-login>@ssh.<your-domain>?*" Yes, exactly! "*This connects me to the ssh session, should I do anything afterwards or just disconnect again?*" Check the `post-receive` hook ran and disconnect. Next time try `ssh -i ~/.ssh/post-receive-key <your-login>@ssh.<your-domain> exit` to pass the command to the remote shell.

Comment: Ah, thank you! 
And then I could just put this in a git-push.sh file?

Comment: Yes. With `command` in `authorized_keys` user-supplied command is ignored so `ssh exit` will not work. Try `command="cd ~/website.git && sh hooks/post-receive && exit"`

Comment: After some experiments I found `exit` is not required — `ssh` executes `command` and disconnects automatically.